# Intent wont start: it says starting intent on console but it just doesn't start

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to make an android app and is currently on log in phase. I tried running my app on the emulator, it has no problems or errors except that the console says that the activity manager is starting the Intent, but it actually doesn't start it. Can someone please help me with this? I am a noob in android programming.

Here is my main activity

```
    package com.ysleps.simbayanan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b;
    EditText et,pass;
    TextView tv;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);  
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", 
                        "Validating user...", true);
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            login();                          
                        }
                      }).start();               
            }
        });
    }

    void login(){
        try{            

            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:81/login/check.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            // edited by James from coderzheaven.. <span id="IL_AD10" class="IL_AD">from here</span>....
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            startActivity(new Intent(this, UserPage.class));
            }else{
                showAlert();                
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void showAlert(){
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
                builder.setMessage("User not Found.")  
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           }
                       });                     
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();               
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use AsyncTask to do this. It is the recommended way to run the background task and you can easily display your progress bar and alerts as well. Please refer this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html This link also has some valuable information about AsyncTask http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: May I ask you if i placed the intent properly? @virtualpathum

Comment: As fas as I understand your code I can't see you are starting any new intent. That's why I suggested to use a AsyncTask may be in a Seperate Activity and start that activity on your button click

Comment: While I am a big fan of `AsyncTask` and I would use it in this situation, I think saying, "It is the recommended way to run the background task" is misleading because this depends on many things such as the developer preference, the situation, and other variables. Also, it probably isn't relevant here since the task wouldn't run until the `Button` is clicked and the app isn't even getting that far.

Comment: this app, so far, goes like this. when i try to log in. I validates the username and password from the server. I did a toast that appears if i successfully logged in, and if the username i entered does not exists on the database. And then what i'm trying to do is when its successful and the user is found, it would go to the next page. so After the toast is where i put my intent, but it does not direct to my next page which is the userpage.xml. I was wondering if I'm just really doing this Intent thing the wrong way.

Comment: @user3239540 so the app is starting and you can click the `Button`?

Comment: yes. i only have a log in button and a single xml file. plus the xml file where i am trying to direct it if the user is found. My app says successfully login but it stops there, it does not go to the next page.

Comment: @codeMagic as far as I understand the code everything is running on the UI thread and I don't think it's a good practice . that's why I suggested to use AsyncTask.  try changing like this and see  startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPage.class));

Comment: @virtualpathum a new `Thread` is created in the `onClick()` so that would happen in the background. The way the post sounded was that the app was never started and the `Button` was never clicked. But apparently that's not what is happening.

Comment: i am sorry if my post appeared that way. but the app starts, and it the validation of the username and password happens. My only problem is it does not go to the next page even if its successfully logged in. I am not sure if my Intent part is quite right, but i think it is because i've searched a lot about how to do it and they appear that way. So i was really wondering what might be wrong with this and how can i fix this.

Comment: Did you try changing startActivity(new Intent(this, UserPage.class)); to startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPage.class));  ?

Comment: yes. i've tried all kinds of creating an Intent. it still does not work.

Comment: Try adding the creating intent under the run() like this runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login                Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPage.class)); 
                    }
                });

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: it says Fatal error in main. and another time it say show statusIcon on inactive inputconnection.

Comment: I (FINALLY!!) managed to make it go to the next page using this Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPage.class); MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent); MainActivity.this.finish(); but something wierd's happening. my layout automatically rotates even when its orentation vertically set.

Comment: Nice to hear that! You better post new question about the layout issue with your xml file and if this you think this answer was helpful just up vote it

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you added this code in your AndroidManifest.xml.Like that

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity 
        android:name="com.abcd.yourmainactivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You can delete all the codes first,just save the 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.main);}.That can make sure your configuration is right.